# Change to nofollow tag in wp-login.php

Tags: login, nofollow

In wp-login.php default is:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

I want to change it to:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

Is there an easy way or script to change this?

Comment: Any reason you want to do that?

Comment: It's entirely possible that an external theme or plugin has injected unwanted links into the login page via actions or filters. @cybmeta

Comment: What? Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with external theme, external plugin and unwanted links. Anyway, can you explain how adding `noindex,nofollow` robot meta tag can help with that and what benefits you get comparing with the default `noindex, follow`? If you have unwanted links, **remove them**.

Comment: My reason is some SEO requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending @prosti answer, WordPress add it using action `login_head` in `wp-login.php` itself.

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_no_robots' );
```

You can remove this action in theme/plugin and add your own action with custom callback function.

Example:-

```
//Keep priority 9 so we can remove WordPress action that is on 10
add_action( 'login_head', 'custom_no_robots', 9);
/**
 * Custom robot tags
 */
function custom_no_robots() {
    remove_action( 'login_head', 'wp_no_robots' );
    echo "<meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />\n";
}
```

Comment: I really like this remove_action. This is a great plus and smarter then possible filtering.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize your WordPress login page with this action hook.

```
function f1() {
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" >' . "\n";
}
add_action('login_head', 'f1');
```

The later one meta tag will prevail the original. PS. You can use filter if you plan to remove the original meta tag.